# How to use session management with Load Balancer in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, load-balancing

I have four different server and a load balancer. I want to use captcha control. I did something with it this way:

I created a handler.ashx to create the captcha image. This handler is used in the Main page. I keep the captcha control password in session while creating the captcha control. Then I compared password typed by the user with the password in the session. It works very well, but only on one server.

It doesn't run correctly with four servers. Although the user enters the correct password every time, it sometimes matches with the session password and sometimes doesn't match. I think the problem reason is this:

For Example :

A,B,C and D are the four servers.  The load balancer routes the first request to A server. Which opens the main page from A server and creates password '123456'.  This is stored in session on A server.  Then user typed in the password and clicked button.  Now the load balancer routes this request to the B server.  Because session in B Sever is null, the passwords don't match.

My web.config has this,

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"/>
```

But It still doesnt work.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first thing (just to make sure) - I believe that this connection string is just an example because 127.0.0.1 is localhost and it wouldn't have chance to work ;).

Now I will assume that you have chosen server A for you state server. Please check following things:

- "ASP.NET State Service" is up and running on the server A (it's disabled by default, you can check that in Administrative Tools --> Services)
- the stateConnectionString in servers B, C and D is "tcpip=[Server A IP Address or Network Name]:42424" (it can be 127.0.0.1 only on server A)
- servers can communicate between each other using TCP/IP via port 42424 (firewalls etc.)

Please remember that if you have changed configuration of "ASP.NET State Service" on server A to not use default port (42424), you must reflect that in your connection strings.

Sometimes it's easier to configure "SQL Server Mode" instead of "State Server Mode" so you might want to consider that. You can find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx).

Comment: I tried it. But it still doesnt work. A Server Ip : 192.168.50.51. B Server Ip: 192.168.50.52. A Server tcpip = 127.0.0.1:42424 in webconfig. B Server tcpip = 192.168.50.51:42424 in webconfig. I started asp.net service. I have got a error. http://postimage.org/image/5u6rjoknr/ . Then I changed this value "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnections". I set as "1". But  it still doesnt work.

Comment: The error message is saying that B server can't connect to A server. There might be a number of network issues. Have you checked that communication from B to A on this port is possible? Also have you changed this setting on A or B? And is there an error messege when you try to login directly to A?

Comment: All ports of between A and B is open. I dont change port setting. They use '42424'. A is working. But B isnt working. B is giving the error.

Comment: So it definitely proves that there is communication problem between B and A. Server B just can't connect to state server on A, there must by some network issue. You might need to contact with your network admin to help you resolve the issue.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your interest. Issue was solved. It wasnt network issue. The issue reason is server state configuration on IIS. Connection string of Server state setting on IIS was 'tcpip=localhost:42424' . I changed it as 'tcpip=192.168.50.51:42424'. It works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use StateServer or SqlServer for managing the session state and they should be out of your firewall network that is used to balance the load.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LoadBalancingAndASPNET.aspx

Comment: +1 for this.  You have to share session state between the machines.  The only way to do this is to setup a machine as the "state" server.  This could mean storing it in your sql database server or in an additional purpose built server.  Either way, it has to be somewhere accessible by all of the web servers.

Answer (score 0):

When using Session State Server, there are few things which need to setup.

1. Setup ASP.Net State Service on the machine which you want as a StateServer.

   > net start aspstate
2. Change Session Mode in Web.Config File for all web applications and point to a StateServer

> ```
> <system.web>
>     <!-- ... -->
>     <sessionState
>         mode="StateServer"
>         stateConnectionString="tcpip=your_server_ip:42424"
>         cookieless="false"
>         timeout="20" />
>     <!-- ... -->
> </system.web>
> ```

3 . All Web Server the use same `<machinekey>` configuration

> ```
> <machineKey 
>   validationKey="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890AAAAAAAAAA"
>   decryptionKey="123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678"
>   validation="SHA1"
>   decryption="Auto"
> />
> ```

([Note](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325056):To maintain session state across different Web servers in the Web farm, the application path of the Web site (for example, \LM\W3SVC\2) in the Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) metabase must be the same for all of the Web servers in the Web farm. The case also needs to be the same because the application path is case-sensitive.
[http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325056])

Comment: I have machineKey.     <machineKey validationKey="3AE041467624C0947FE562E2DBE6122B532FBC4AA9845AE3D82EC6AC473104EA40A27F8E89BADDAEE44B1F7582FC47299B674ED1FD2DDE1368710504EB2C54C1" decryptionKey="2FC79A393A5A463F82D38828F43ED7D030C418B448C9E76C" validation="SHA1"/>. Although it still gives error.